# What Cocoa APIs should I be learning to build a UI similar to Tictoc? (pics included)

Tags: macos, cocoa

I really dig the way Tictoc anchors to its toolbar item but I'm not sure which APIs I should be learning to replicate that feature. The two things I'm hoping to learn are:

- Adding an item to the system menu bar
- Anchoring my window to the menu bar

Here's a screenshot for anyone who hasn't had a chance to use this app:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an item to the menu bar, check out [NSStatusItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

There are a few options for windows resembling the one in your screenshot, but I recommend [Matt Gemmell's](http://mattgemmell.com/) MAAttachedWindow.  There's a link to it [here](http://mattgemmell.com/source/), including a project which does the NSStatusItem thing.

Comment: Looks like a great start. Thanks!